# Java Code solves 3x3 and 5x5 magic squares but not 4x4 and 6x6

Tags: java

Hey guys new to programming here. I have a project on magic squares and my code can solve 3x3 and 5x5 but not 44 and 6x6 arrays for some reason. To give some info about the project we make a program that should give the user 4 option to solve a magic square (using an arraylist as a stack or as queue, a stack and a linked list as a queue). The code makes copies of the magic square and each of them has a new cell filled with a number according to the check methods and its i,j position. Each copy is created checked and filled if possible in the nextSuccessor() method. if at least a number can fill the cell the copy is returned to the main program to be stored in the data structure the user has chosen in the beginning of the program. If no number could fill the cell the method returns null. The program ends when either all the cells of a copy of a magic square are filled, or if the data structure gets empty.

ps: That first constructor that is in the MagicSquare class is what we were instructed to do so that's why i made the set method.

Here are the two classes:

```
public class MagicSquare{
    int N;
    int C;
    int[][] magic; // NxN. 
    int numbers; //counts how many number have been used 
    boolean[] used; // NxN length
    int row, col; //point the cell to be filled
    int current_number; // the number that will be checked to fill the magic[row][col] 

    public MagicSquare(){ 
        N=0;
        magic = new int[N][N];
        C = N*(N*N + 1)/2;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
                magic[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
        numbers = 0;
        used = new boolean[N*N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N*N; i++){
            used[i] = false;
        }
    }

    public MagicSquare(MagicSquare obj){
        N = obj.N;
        C = obj.C;
        magic = new int[N][N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
               magic[i][j] = obj.magic[i][j];
            }
        }
        numbers = obj.numbers;
        used = new boolean[N*N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N*N; i++){
            used[i] = obj.used[i];
        }
    }

    public void setNandValues(int n, int[][] a){
        N = n;
        C = N*(N*N + 1)/2;
        magic = new int[N][N];
        used = new boolean[N*N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < N; j++){
                magic[i][j] = a[i][j];
                if (magic[i][j] != 0) {
                    used[magic[i][j] -1] = true;
                    numbers++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void initialize_successor(){
        row = -1;
        col = -1;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < N && row == -1){
            int j = 0;
            while (j<N && col == -1){
               if (magic[i][j] == 0){
                this.row = i;
                this.col = j;
               }
               j++;
            }
            i++;
        }
        current_number=0;
    }

    public boolean checkRow(){
        int m = 0;
        int s = current_number;
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            if (magic[row][i] == 0){
                m++;
            }
            else s += magic[row][i];
        }
        m--;
        
        if (m>0){
            int i = 0;
            int k = 0;
            while(i<N && k<m){
                if(i != current_number-1 && used[i] == false){
                    a += i+1;
                    k += 1;
                }
                i++;
            }
            /*while(i > 0){
                if (used[k] == false){
                    a += (k+1);
                    i--;
                    if (k == current_number - 1){
                        a -= (k+1);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                k++;
            }*/
            /*i = m;
            k = 0;
            while(i > 0){
                if (used[N*N-k-1] == false){
                    b += (N*N-k);
                    i--;
                    if (k == current_number - 1){
                        b -= (N*N-k);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                k++;
            } */
            i = 0;
            k = 0;
            while(i<N*N && k<m){
                if(i != current_number-1 && used[N*N-i-1] == false){
                    b += N*N - i;
                    k += 1;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        return (s+a<=C && s+b>=C);
    }

    public boolean checkCol(){
        int m = 0;
        int s = current_number;
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            if (magic[i][col] == 0){
                m++;
            }
            else s += magic[i][col];
        }
        m--;
        if (m>0){
            int i = m;
            int k = 0;
            /*while(i > 0){
                if (used[k] == false){
                    a += (k+1);
                    i--;
                    if (k == current_number - 1){
                        a -= (k+1);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                k++;
            }*/
            while(i<N && k<m){
                if(i != current_number-1 && used[i] == false){
                    a += i+1;
                    k += 1;
                }
                i++;
            }
            /*i = m;
            k = 0;
            while(i > 0){
                if (used[N*N-k-1] == false){
                    b += (N*N-k);
                    i--;
                    if (k == current_number - 1){
                        b -= (N*N-k);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                k++;
            }*/
            i = 0;
            k = 0;
            while(i<N*N && k<m){
                if(i != current_number-1 && used[N*N-i-1] == false){
                    b += N*N - i;
                    k += 1;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        return (s+a<=C && s+b>=C);
    }

    public boolean checkMainDiagonal() {
        int m = 0;
        int s = current_number;
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            if (magic[i][i] == 0){
                m++;
            }
            else s += magic[i][i];
        }
        m--;
        if (m>0){
            int i = m;
            int k = 0;
            /*while(i > 0){
                if (used[k] == false){
                    a += (k+1);
                    i--;
                    if (k == current_number - 1){
                        a -= (k+1);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                k++;
            }*/
            while(i<N && k<m){
                if(i != current_number-1 && used[i] == false){
                    a += i+1;
                    k += 1;
                }
                i++;
            }
            /*i = m;
            k = 0;
            while(i > 0){
                if (used[N*N-k-1] == false){
                    b += (N*N-k);
                    i--;
                    if (k == current_number - 1){
                        b -= (N*N-k);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                k++;
            }*/
            i = 0;
            k = 0;
            while(i<N*N && k<m){
                if(i != current_number-1 && used[N*N-i-1] == false){
                    b += N*N - i;
                    k += 1;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        return (s+a<=C && s+b>=C);
    }
    
    public boolean checkSecondaryDiagonal() {
        int m = 0;
        int s = current_number;
        int a = 0;
        int b = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
            if (magic[i][N-i-1] == 0){
                m++;
            }
            else s += magic[i][N-i-1];
        }
        m--;
        if (m>0){
            int i = m;
            int k = 0;
            /*while(i > 0){
                if (used[k] == false){
                    a += (k+1);
                    i--;
                    if (k == current_number - 1){
                        a -= (k+1);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                k++;
            }*/
            while(i<N && k<m){
                if(i != current_number-1 && used[i] == false){
                    a += i+1;
                    k += 1;
                }
                i++;
            }
            /*i = m;
            k = 0;
            while(i > 0){
                if (used[N*N-k-1] == false){
                    b += (N*N-k);
                    i--;
                    if (k == current_number - 1){
                        b -= (N*N-k);
                        i++;
                    }
                }
                k++;
            }*/
            i = 0;
            k = 0;
            while(i<N*N && k<m){
                if(i != current_number-1 && used[N*N-i-1] == false){
                    b += N*N - i;
                    k += 1;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }
        return (s+a<=C && s+b>=C);
    }
    
    public MagicSquare nextSuccessor(){
        MagicSquare m;
            while( current_number < N*N){
                current_number++;
                if( !used[ current_number -1]){
                    if(((this.row != this.col && this.row != N-this.col -1) && (this.checkRow() && this.checkCol())) ||
                    (this.row == this.col && this.row != N-this.col -1) && (this.checkRow() && this.checkCol() && this.checkMainDiagonal()) ||
                    (this.row != this.col && this.row == N-this.col -1) && (this.checkRow() && this.checkCol() && this.checkSecondaryDiagonal()) ||
                    (this.row == this.col && this.row == N-this.col -1) && (this.checkRow() && this.checkCol() && this.checkMainDiagonal() && this.checkSecondaryDiagonal())){
                        magic[row][col] = current_number;
                        used[current_number - 1] = true;
                        m = new MagicSquare();
                        m.setNandValues(N, magic);
                        return m;
                    }
                }
            }
        return null;
    }

    /*
    public MagicSquare nextSuccessor(){
        MagicSquare m;
            while( current_number < N*N){
                current_number++;
                if( !used[ current_number -1] && checkRow() && checkCol()){
                    magic[row][col] = current_number;
                    used[current_number - 1] = true;
                    m = new MagicSquare();
                    m.setNandValues(N, magic);
                    return m;
                }
            }
        return null;
    }
 */

    public void display(){
        for (int i =0; i<N; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<N; j++){
                System.out.print(magic[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }         

} 

/*
    public MagicSquare nextSuccessor(){
        MagicSquare m;
            while( current_number < N*N){
                current_number++;
                if( !used[ current_number -1] && checkRow() && checkCol()){
                    magic[row][col] = current_number;
                    used[current_number - 1] = true;
                    m = new MagicSquare();
                    m.setNandValues(N, magic);
                    return m;
                }
            }
        return null;
    }
 */
```

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainSolver {
    static int[][] pin;
    static int N;
    static ArrayList<MagicSquare> frontierAL;
    static Stack<MagicSquare> frontierST;
    static LinkedList<MagicSquare> frontierLL;
    //String filename = args[0]; 
    //int option = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
    static String filename = "/Users/panagiotispagonis/Documents/ΠΜΣ/ΠΛΣ 50/Εργασίες ΠΛ50/Εργασία 3/Εργασία 3 (code)/Thema1/p4-01.txt";
    static int option; 
    static void readMagicSquare(String filename){
        try {
            File obj = new File(filename);
            Scanner read = new Scanner(obj);
            N = Integer.parseInt(read.nextLine());
            pin = new int[N][N];    
            for(int i = 0; i<N; i++) {
                String data = read.nextLine();
                String[] row =data.split(" ");
                for (int j= 0; j < N; j++){
                    pin[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(row[j]); 
                }
            }
            read.close();
            }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("An error has occurred.");
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        static void initialize_search(MagicSquare s, int datastructure) {
            switch (datastructure) {
                case 1:
                case 2:
                    frontierAL = new ArrayList<MagicSquare>();
                    frontierAL.add(s);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    frontierST=new Stack<MagicSquare>();
                    frontierST.push(s);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    frontierLL=new LinkedList<MagicSquare>();
                    frontierLL.add(s);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
        // arxikopoiei ti domi pou tha xrisimopoiithei apo to programma se kathe periptosi. auto krinetai apo to poia epilogi patise o xristis (option)
        static void search(int datastructure) {
            MagicSquare current = null, next;
            switch (datastructure) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Search using ArrayList as a Stack");
                    break;
                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Search using ArrayList as a Queue");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Search using Stack as a Stack");
                    break;
                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Search using LinkedList as a Queue");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        
            boolean empty_frontier=false;
            
            while (!empty_frontier) {
                if (datastructure==1) {
                    current=frontierAL.get(frontierAL.size()-1);
                    frontierAL.remove(frontierAL.size()-1);
                }
                else if (datastructure==2) {
                    current=frontierAL.get(0);
                    frontierAL.remove(0);
                }
                else if (datastructure==3)
                    current=frontierST.pop();
                else if (datastructure==4)
                    current=frontierLL.removeFirst();
    
                current.initialize_successor();
                while((next=current.nextSuccessor())!=null)
                {

                    if (next.numbers==N*N)
                    {
                        System.out.println("\nSOLUTION FOUND ");
                        System.out.println("==============");
                        next.display();
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                    switch (datastructure) {
                        case 1: ;
                        case 2: {frontierAL.add(next);
                            break;}
                        case 3: { frontierST.push(next);
                            break;}
                        case 4:{ frontierLL.addLast(next);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
    
                switch (datastructure) {
                    case 1:
                        if (frontierAL.isEmpty())
                            empty_frontier=true;
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (frontierAL.isEmpty())
                            empty_frontier=true;
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        if (frontierST.isEmpty())
                            empty_frontier=true;
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        if (frontierLL.isEmpty())
                            empty_frontier=true;
                        break;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("\nPUZZLE CANNOT BE SOLVED");
        }
    

    public static void main(String[] args){
        //Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        //String filename = args[0]; 
        //int option = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        readMagicSquare(filename);
        MagicSquare sqr = new MagicSquare();
        sqr.setNandValues(N, pin);
        initialize_search(sqr, option);
        search(option);
    }
}
```

At first i thought i was missing something in my while loops so i wrote them as "childish" as possible. Still nothing... Everything i tried is as a comment in the classes' code.

So Any ideas?

Comment: That's **a lot** of code to dump onto us without a precise error description. I suggest you *at least* describe what exactly happens when trying to solve a 4x4 magic square. Does it stop with some error message? Does it crash? Stack trace? What happens? And **ideally** you could narrow the problem down to some method that doesn't do what you intended it to and point us towards that.

Comment: that is the reason debuggers are developed, in case you don't have a debugging PA and have to do it yourself

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).